# javascript:window.close() and Opera

Tags: javascript, opera

I'm using asp.net web forms. I add simple javascript function to button OnClientClick - I need to close window. But this simple peace of code stop working in Opera (12.10) after form data was changed:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function CloseCurrentWindow(sender, args) {
            window.close(); // self.close() and this.close() act similar
        }
    </script>
```

Does anybody know such kind of issue (and, maybe, solution).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few hours of investigation, I've figured out that currently browser Opera doesn't support window.colse() function on objects (windows) that was created using _target=blanck. Only those windows that was created using javascript can be handled by javascript, which is sad..

Hope in future they will change this behavior to more user-friendly (or developer-friendly)

Comment: Too bad they haven't...Still... The year of our lord 2014.