# Facebook login dialog doesn't close using javascript SDK

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I've tried to do the facebook login using FB Javascript SDK.

After login doesn't close the login window only in opera browser.
How can i fix this problem?

I've tried following source code:
(on-line in [this website - LINK](http://www.milujse.cz/app/login.html))

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

        FB.init({
          appId: '101103500012652', // App ID
          channelUrl: '//www.milujse.cz/app/channel.html', // Channel File
          status: true,
          cookie: true,
          xfbml: true
        });

        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {

          if (response.status === 'connected') {
            testAPI();
          } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {

          } else {

          }
        });
      };

      (function(d) {
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {
          return;
        }
        js = d.createElement('script');
        js.id = id;
        js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
      }(document));

      function testAPI() {
        FB.api('/me', function(response) {
          alert('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
        });
      }

      function loginFB()
      {
        FB.login(function(response) {
          if (response.authResponse) {
            testAPI();
          } else {
          }
        });
      }

      function logoutFB()
      {
        FB.logout(function(response) {
        });
      }
    </script>

    <input type="button" value="Login" onclick="loginFB();
        return false;" />
    <input type="button" value="Logout" onclick="logoutFB();
        return false;" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you seeing any javascript errors in the console?

Comment: In the console isn't the javascript error.

Comment: I had similar issues with my Facebook implementation in other browsers. I had to pass the callback function through the login and api methods to maintain state, but I don't know if this is related to your Opera issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered checking the browser and if it's Opera using the other way to connect with facebook, I mean with oauth you can redirect the whole page to the facebook login page instead of using a popup and so you wont have the problem of not being able to close the popup.
The link to the whole page si something like 
"https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=http:YOUR_CALLBACK-URL&scope=WHAT_YOU_WANT"

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a bug in Opera in that Opera doesn't support the window.close() function on windows under some curcumstances.

This is referred to at [javascript:window.close() and Opera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12618674/javascriptwindow-close-and-opera) as well as at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=190515 where this is listed as a bug.

It seems the window.closed() event is buggy too in Opera, as per http://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/5687

Answer (score 1):

For example programming browser independent login/logout logic on closing the browser is hard to implement in consequence.

Checked using code below and setting the breakpoint at setUser(null)

package com.example.vaadintests;

import com.vaadin.Application;
import com.vaadin.ui.Window;
import com.vaadin.ui.Window.CloseEvent;
import com.vaadin.ui.Window.CloseListener;

```
public class VaadintestsApplication extends Application 
{
    @Override
    public void init() 
    {
        final Window rootWindow = new Window();
        setMainWindow(rootWindow);

        rootWindow.addListener(new CloseListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void windowClose(CloseEvent e)
            {
                setUser(null);
            }
        });

    }
}
```